# When does the binary operators execution happen in Java?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

I'm trying to understand java byte code. I started with simple example:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(2 + 1);
    }
}
```

I compiled this class:

```
javac Test.java
```

And then I tried to a `javap` on the .class like this:

```
javap -c Test
```

which gave me this:

```
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: iconst_1      
       4: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
       7: return        
}
```

I could able to make sense out of it, apart from this line:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
. . . 
3: iconst_1    
. . .
```

looking at my source and this byte code, looks like javac already done the operation of addition for this statement:

```
2+1
```

and asking jvm to return that constant.

Can some one correct me if my understanding is wrong? Does javac performs the operation on compilation for `+`,`-`,`*` etc before it actually runs on the jvm? If so how?

Comment: It's a constant, optimized at compile time.

Comment: The "how" is pretty easy-math. The compiler knows those are numbers, can't change, and they're addable.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

2 + 1 is a compile-time constant expression. The compiler itself replaces it by 3 in the byte-code.

See the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.2), which says:

> Some expressions have a value that can be determined at compile time. These are constant expressions.

See [this other chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) for what constitutes a constant expression

> A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following:
>
> - Literals of primitive type and literals of type String [...]
> - The additive operators + and -
>   [...]

Comment: So all constant expression is being resolved by compiler?

Comment: @batman yes, but notice that `1 + 2 + i` and `i + 1 + 2` will be compiled as `3 + i` and `i + 1 + 2`. It happens because of order of operation which in first case is `(1 + 2) + i` so `(1+2)` can be optimized by compiler, but in case of `(i+1) + 2` in `(i + 1)` compiler can't know value of `i` at compilation time, so it will not optimize your code.

Comment: @Pshemo: Thats an bit of interesting info, on how an parenthesis helps the compiler optimisation. Thanks!

Comment: Another practical usage is to define long strings, like a SQL query, on multiple lines for example. Or a duration like ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS = 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L.

Comment: The compiler doesn't _have_ to optimize constant expressions, it's just encouraged to and does in practice.

Comment: @Pshemo: In particular, while `i+1+2 == i+3` is, in fact, always true for integers, it's *not* always true for floating point numbers. For [a counterexample](http://ideone.com/WTs4HJ), try `double i = 1e16;`.

Comment: The only question that remains is why in the OPs environment `2+1` is evaluated to `1`…